# Independent variables in truncated Weibull distribution

Tags: regression, random-variable, weibull-distribution

I am relative new to statistics and currently working on a problem about crash rate analysis. It is appears to be a zero-inflated scenario, then I decide to use the hurdle model. The first part will use the logit model to determine if crash rate is 0 or positive. For the positive part, found the dependent variable (crash rate) distribution close to Weibull distribution, and it is right-truncated. Then, I used the expectation formula (two-parameters) similar to this
[image]

and corresponding MLE function. Now I face the problem, how to connect the independent variables with the expectation function? Substitute some variables?
Many thanks.

Comment: If you don't currently have any independent variables then you're looking at the distribution of the response on its own. This is the marginal distribution of the response, but the model will be for the *conditional* distribution (i.e. given the values of the predictors/IVs). So what you're looking at now is a mixture of the conditional distributions over the values of the predictors. That might look Weibull but it doesn't imply that the conditional distributions will look anything like that. It might -- but it may look quite different, even to having skewness of the opposite sign, for example